# React JS tree view to display api response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, treeview, react-bootstrap

In my react application, I am implementing a tree view structure to display the api response in more readable format. I am using tree view-react-bootstrap for that.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TreeView from 'treeview-react-bootstrap'

class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        // SET YOUR DATA
        this.state = {
            data: [
                {
                    text: "John Peter",
                    nodes: [
                      {
                        text: "ID: 11111",
                        nodes: [
                          {
                            text: "VIN"
                          },
                          {
                            text: "Policy Effective Date"
                          },
                          {
                            text: "Policy Expiration Date"
                          },
                          {
                            text: "Vehicle Make"
                          },
                          {
                            text: "Vehicle Model"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        text: "ID: 123456",
                        nodes: [
                            {
                              text: "VIN"
                            },
                            {
                              text: "Policy Effective Date"
                            },
                            {
                              text: "Policy Expiration Date"
                            },
                            {
                              text: "Vehicle Make"
                            },
                            {
                              text: "Vehicle Model"
                            }
                          ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    text: "Scott Brown"
                  }
            ]
        }

    }

    render(){
        return (
            // RENDER THE COMPONENT
            <TreeView data={this.state.data} />
        );
    }
}

export default Example
```

I am using dummy data for now but this is the format that I want my data to be displayed. The api response I have is "array of objects" and it is only in one level JSON format.

Sample response -

```
[
                    {
                        "id": "1234",
                        "name": "John Scott",
                        "vin": "45",
                        "make": "Toyota",
                        "model": "Etios"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "4567",
                        "name": "James Scott",
                        "vin": "67",
                        "make": "Hyundai",
                        "model": "Etios"
                    }
]
```

If you see the response, I would like my key value to be printed in a tree structure.

Is there a way I can render this response to accommodate with treeview-react-bootstrap?

I am not sure if I need to use map function inside my render method to iterate and display the data and how will it work along.Can someone let me know if I am doing it right or is there any better way of doing it. thanks in advance.

Comment: In your api response you need to have relations between the array elements. How do you determine that ?

Comment: I am only try to pick up the key and values to display in this format. So there are two attributes i.e id which I will take as a parent node and add few other attributes as its child.This is what my idea is but not sure if I can make this work without changing the backend.

Comment: You can make an Ajax call using axion in componentDidMount and once you get the response you can set the response in this state.

Comment: yeah, but how can I render the response in the above format?

Comment: You can transform your response from server and then set the state. If you can share a sample response from server, then I can help more.

Comment: I have added the sample response above. I want to pick the keys and value and show it in a tree view.

Comment: Have added an answer. You should be able to transform as per your needs.

Comment: sure, let me try that.will update here.

Comment: I am actually using redux for all my api calls. facing issue with setState- says "cannot read property setState of undefined". Do I have to use it as componentWillreceiveProps in my comp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the response something like this. Have just added a dummy response. Please check the following code and let me know if this helps:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TreeView from "treeview-react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // SET YOUR DATA
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get("https://www.mocky.io/v2/5bb85d723000005f00f93bb6")
            .then(data => {
                let transformedData = data.data.map(d => {
                    return {
                        text: d.text,
                        nodes: [
                            {
                                text: "dummy 1",
                                nodes: []
                            }
                        ]
                    };
                });
                this.setState({ data: transformedData });
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // RENDER THE COMPONENT
            <TreeView data={this.state.data} />
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

You can also see it in action here: https://codesandbox.io/s/73ryny9ywq?autoresize=1&hidenavigation=1